# When was the last time a kicker was released after making two 60+ yard field goals during the season?

Tags: trivia, american-football, statistics, nfl, transaction

In 2019, [Brett Maher](http://www.nfl.com/player/brettmaher/2540243/gamelogs) made a 62 and 63 yard field goals during the season. However, he was [released](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/0ap3000001086230/article/cowboys-cut-kicker-brett-maher-sign-kai-forbath) on 9 Dec 2019.

When was the last time a kicker was released after making two (or more) 60+ yard field goals during the season? Please state the kicker's name, team, yards of field goals he made over 60 yards, and his date of release.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Here] is an image of the data you request.  The rest is left as an exercise to the reader.

It would seem I cannot view this by clicking.

This information is readily available at Football Reference dot com.

additional info: only three kickers have made more than 1 60+ yard FG in their career.

Maher has made 3 (two this season), Greg Zuerlein has made 2 (three seasons apart), and Sebastian Janikowski has made 2 (two seasons apart).

In other words, it has never happened otherwise.